# Recovering SQL database when OS crashed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I was working on a DB design its almost finished. But missed to take a backup.
While working due to some reason my OS got crashed (Win 10) and nothing helped to recover it.

But I am able to access the hdd contents when connecting in another PC.

So is there is anyway to recover the DB using an SQL server express installation on that PC.

On googling I have found there is some attach option using MDF files

But I am not able to find the MDF files in the Program Files\MS SQL server folder

Where SQL server express 2019 is storing MDF files by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a file search tool, such as [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/), since the database file paths could be set to anywhere, depending on what was chosen when the database itself was created (after the SQL Server instance was installed).

Otherwise you can find information regarding the default paths of SQL Server in [Specifying File Paths docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#specifying-file-paths).

You'll want to take all **MDF**, **NDF**, and **LDF** files pertaining to your database(s) together. Then you should be able to **Attach** them to a new SQL Server instance by following [these instructions per Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. Lots of respect..

Comment: @sanforall No problem, glad to be of assistance!

Comment: The pre-requisite in that link link says that `If you attempt to attach a database that has not been detached returns an error.`

Comment: @variable That's not very possible in OP's situation where the system crashed and the instance no longer exists. But that's also not necessarily true (not sure why it says that in the docs) as I've moved / copied databases to different drives and instances without explicitly detaching them. Usually I take the source database or instance service offline, and then it's possible to move and re-attach then to a new instance. It may be that those actions also implicitly emulate detaching the database too, not sure.

Comment: Had this been a real production system crash, then can system dbs also be attached directly or do they need to be restored from backup?

Comment: @variable The system databases need to be restored from backups as far as I know. Note I saw your recent question relating to this, and will post an answer to it (hopefully soon). So let's not create an extended discussion on this answer.

Comment: Thanks yes I can't find any clear document from Microsoft for this.